# Nuxt.js: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, persistence

I am using Nuxt.js. The following problem occurred with setting up vuex-persist. Could someone help me?

store/index.js

[image: image one]

store/LangModule.js

[image: image two]

[image: image three]

Comment: you cant call `window` on store file. you have to import it as plugin and call it on cliend side not server side, please read the documentation. already mention there https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to know Nuxt works on both server and client sides, so you cannot use `window` in all places since it only exists on client side.

You can declare this plugin SSR-free to avoid running it on server side.

Following the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist#tips-for-nuxt):

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

**~/plugins/vuex-persist.js**

```
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'
 
export default ({ store }) => {
  new VuexPersistence({
  /* your options */
  }).plugin(store);
}
```